# Is a Swift program really deployed like that?

Tags: swift, tomcat, gwt

> Swift program deploys the application in a Tomcat installation by
>   default. The deploy script bundles the client code into JavaScript,
>   gathers all the server side classes required and packages them into
>   file Hello.war. This file together with a GWT jar and a Swift runtime
>   jar is copied into the Tomcat installation. If CATALINA_HOME is not
>   set, these files require to be copied manually.

[Source](http://career.guru99.com/top-15-swift-interview-questions/)

This is wrong, afaik. Can anybody verify?

Comment: that's what...it so misleading....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Apple's Swift.

The author you quote just blindly copied an article about [this other technology named Swift](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/jif/swift/doc/) for this paragraph.

This other technology is about writing Web applications "as if they were desktop programs in a Java-like source language": this is not related to Apple's Swift in any way.